# Setting up DNS settings for Azure in DirectAdmin and CPanel

Tags: azure, dns, cpanel, directadmin

I am just starting my adventure with Azure and have encountered quite a few problems with setting up DNS settings for two domains, one with CPanel as management portal and the other one with DirectAdmin.

CPanel

The domain with Cpanel is setup correctly so that I can visit it at domain.com rather than domain.azurewebsites.net, but had a lot of troubles with receiving e-mails. Through my research I found out that the best solution is to get Google Apps or Microsoft 365 and host the domain on DNSimple. Is that right? Is there a way to sort it out without paying for services such as Google Apps/365 or programming mail receiver and sender in code?

DirectAdmin

I cannot get DNS set up properly at all. At first, similarly to what I did with Cpanel domain, I pointed "www.domain.com." to "www.domain.azurewebsites.net" and "awverify.domain.com." to "awverify.domain.azurewebsites.net". I also point to the IP given by Azure via A record "www" to "Azure IP". It didn't work so I thought I'll make a subdomain and repeat the steps from before but this time for azure.domain.com. Still no luck.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Apologies if the question is too broad. If need any more information let me know.

Answer (score 0):

it might be because as per rfc it is invalid 
domain.com IN CNAME host.cloudapp.net ==> invalid

this article explain how to do it using either CNAME or A
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/

there is a proposed DNAME but i havent tested it to be working yet.